# Elasticsearch Error "top is below bottom corner error"

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core, nest

I have following error in Elasticsearch

Error

> {Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "top is below bottom corner:
>   41.27072281070173 vs. 69.22146114208326"}

my code is

```
var Buildingpoints= _elasticClient.Search<ElasticSearchModel>(
                     s => s.From(0).Size(600).Query(query => query.Bool(b => b
                     .Filter(filter => filter
                    .GeoBoundingBox(g => g
                    .Boost(1.1)
                    .Name("Location")
                    .Field(p => p.Location)
                    .BoundingBox(c => c
                    .TopLeft(model.Points.X1, model.Points.Y1)
                    .BottomRight(model.Points.X2, model.Points.Y2)
                     )
                    .ValidationMethod(GeoValidationMethod.Strict)
                    .Type(GeoExecution.Indexed)
                    )
                    )


                        )
               ));
```

I am new in elastic search, help me to solve this problem.
***ERROR*** "{ServerError: 400Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed"}"
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch is just telling you that bounding box corners constraint is not met. Bottom corner needs to be "below" top corner.

Replacing

```
.TopLeft(model.Points.X1, model.Points.Y1)
.BottomRight(model.Points.X2, model.Points.Y2)
```

with

```
.TopLeft(model.Points.X2, model.Points.Y2)
.BottomRight(model.Points.X1, model.Points.Y1)
```

should do the job here.

Comment: thank you for your response, now I have another error "Error{Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed"} Elasticsearch.Net.Error"

Comment: Glad it helped. May you attach `ServerError` from response object into your question?

Comment: {ServerError: 400Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed"} Elasticsearch.Net.ServerError

Comment: Could you call `.ToString()` on `ServerError` or copy information from `DebugInformation`?

Comment: I got this from DebugInformation "Error{Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed"}", and I updated my question added screenshoot of debuginformation.

Comment: Could you please enable `DisableDirectStreaming`([how to do this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html#debug-information)) for this request and repost `DebugInformation` content?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193767/discussion-between-ilyoskhuja-and-rob).